# Issue adding a role when reacting to a post

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm  having an issue adding a role when a user reacts to a post.

How I'm wanting it to function is that when a user joins the Discord server the bot will send send a message using the `on_join` event (for now I'm using the command `test` for testing purposes).

The next step is the `on_reaction_add` event, when the user reacts to this message the bot will add the role to that user.

Here is what I'm working with. I've tested this however, I'm not getting the desired result.

(on discord.py rewrite)

```
 @commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(self, user: discord.Member): #lets change this to the command 'test' for now and change on on_join event later. 
    guildName = user.guild.name
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
    embed.title = "Welcome to {} {}!".format(guildName, user)
    embed.description = "Head over to <#443133907102203912> to have a read up on our rules. Once you have read them please reaction to this post with a :thumbsup:"
    embed.set_image(url='')
    await user.send(embed=embed)

async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user): 
    channelid = '555844758778544160' #The text-channel where the react should happen
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Members") #The role applied when the post is reacted to

    if reaction.message.channel.id != channelid:
        return #So it only happens in the specified channel
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:thumbsup:555844758778544160>":#The reaction (not sure if this should be raw in discord.py rewrite)
        await user.add_roles(user, role)#Adds role when post is reacted to
```

Comment: Is this code in a cog or an extension?  Exactly what version of discord.py are you using?  A recent change broke a lot of backwards compatibility in how extensions and cogs work, so you may be looking at outdated examples.  You need have a `ctx` argument before `user` because the context is being passed in, and you probably also need a `self` in `on_reaction_add` (assuming this code is in a cog).

Comment: This is a cog and I'm using discord.py rewrite

Comment: What version  number?  When did you last update it?  There were breaking changes made a few weeks ago, so if you're using the new code but following an old tutorial/example that may explain your problems.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh discord.py rewrite 1.0.0a

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you for the reply I've posted an answer so I can show you that I have tried this (a few changes added) the react to the message from the user unfortunately still doesn't apply the role have I missed something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for a reaction to a specific message if you need to.  This is handy for times like this, where you maybe want to wait for a reaction then keep doing your coroutine.  I will write the below assuming you're using the most up-to-date rewrite.  You can find the documentation for all this [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/cogs.html):

```
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import Cog, command
listener = Cog.listener

thumbs_up = "\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}"

def react_check(user, msg, emoji):
    def check(reaction, usr):
        return usr==user and reaction.message.id==msg.id and reaction.emoji==emoji
    return check

class MyCog(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        guildName = user.guild.name
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
        embed.title = "Welcome to {} {}!".format(guildName, user)
        embed.description = "Head over to <#443133907102203912> to have a read up on our rules. Once you have read them please reaction to this post with a :thumbsup:"
        embed.set_image(url='')
        msg = await user.send(embed=embed)
        await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=react_check(user, msg, thumbs_up))
        role = get(user.guild.roles, name="Members")
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

Then in your main bot, you need a line that says

```
from mycog import MyCog

bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import random
from .utils import checks
from random import randint
from discord.utils import get


thumbs_up = "\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}"

def react_check(user, msg, emoji):
    def check(reaction, usr):
        return usr==user and reaction.message==msg and reaction.emoji==emoji
    return check

class Welcome(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, user: discord.Member):
        guildName = user.guild.name
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(555844758778544160) 
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
        embed.title = "Welcome to {} {}!".format(guildName, user)
        embed.description = "Head over to <#443133907102203912> to have a read up on our rules. Once you have read them please reaction to this post with a :thumbsup:"
        embed.set_image(url='')
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=react_check(user, msg, thumbs_up))
        role = get(user.guild.roles, name="Members")
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await channel.send('test')# Check 
    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Welcome(bot))
```

Comment: Your event is not in the cog.  It should be indented one more level

Comment: That would be `def react_check(user, msg, emoji):...` ?

Comment: No, `on_member_join`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh ah yes I see the indent error I've just fixed that and test the code again and still I'm not getting any results here is a screenshot https://pasteboard.co/I62lvRn.png it seems to be sending the message when the user joins but when the thumbs up reaction is added to the post  I go to check the users roles and the Members role hasn't been added.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I've just noticed in my console ` File "C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\developer-bot\cogs\welcome.py", line 28, in on_member_join
    await msg.add_reaction(check=react_check(msg, thumbs_up, reaction.emoji))
NameError: name 'reaction' is not defined` 

Though isn't it already defined?

Comment: I don't see `await msg.add_reaction` in your code.  `add_reaction` doesn't need a `check`, it just takes the emoji.

Comment: Update: `reaction.message.id==msg.id` instead of `reaction.message==msg`
Message still doesn't have an __eq__ for ... certain reasons this was the reason the reaction wasn't working.